# Image on full slide in beamer package

Tags: beamer, graphics

I would like to make a slide of only one image without any borders or any other beamer specific element.

I tried :

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=1\paperwidth]{kernel-panic.png}
\end{frame}
```

But I still get a border on the left, top and bottom.

Later edit: `width=1.2\paperwidth` seems to remove top and bottom borders. I still have a left border and some navigation elements on bottom right.

Comment: My guess is that space on top and bottom come from the fact that your picture has other proportions than the `beamer` frame. For the left margin, you might want to check [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334751/93613) to this same(?) [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142569/93613), where I claim it's the easiest way to achieve a full slide image in `beamer`.

Comment: The name of the png file somewhat suggests the purpose of the questions ;)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{test of full size graphic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
    Notice the fancy presentation theme.
\end{frame}

{ % all template changes are local to this group.
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{frame}<article:0>[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[at=(current page.center)] {
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,
                                 width=\paperwidth,
                                 height=\paperheight]{yourimage}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    symbols should be back now
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You have to run beamer twice to get the image centered in the right place.  But if you have any other aux-file tricks (e.g., table of contents) you need to do that anyway.

If you're not already using tikz, you can save your image as a pdf and then use `\includepdf` (part of the [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) package).  This will get you into trouble if you want to print your slides as an article or handout, though.

If you use article mode with your slides, you'll get the image on a full page of the article PDF too.  You probably don't want this.  The `<article:0>` mode specification keeps this frame from being included in any article mode documents.  You could also make a separate `\includegraphics` line for article mode that would format it properly.

Comment: Note that this does not work with \multiinclude

Comment: @TimvanDalen, it did for me. Replace `\includegraphics...` with `\multiinclude[graphics={height=\paperheight}]{yourimage}`.

Comment: This did not center the animated graphic (aka video) I was trying to include using the animate package.  It put it on the page but it was not centered (though the part overhanging the page was strangely still visible, just off the page).

Comment: Depending on the aspect ratio of your image, you may need to replace `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{yourimage}` with `\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{yourimage}`

Comment: @Digger: right you are.  In fact, I think you can get whichever is appropriate with (untested) `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{yourimage}`

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Great trick!  Except that it didn't start working correctly for me until I put the `keepaspectratio` switch first (`\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{yourimage}`).

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the improvements suggested by the last three comments.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Your answer seems to flush out the `headline` and the `footline`. I tried changing `height` to `height=\textheight`, but to no avail.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul yes, the `plain` option to the `frame` environment suppresses the headline and footline. I used this option because OP wanted “only one image _without any borders or any other beamer specific element_”. If sounds like you want something else, so ask a different question.

Answer (score 37):

The following strategy worked, but not when I had `\mode*` in operation.

```
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{figure}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}
```

The following seems to work when I have `\mode*` operating in the document.

```
\mode<all>
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{figure}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}
\mode<all>{\usebackgroundtemplate{}}
\mode*
```

Comment: You can simplify things by adding another group around your frame. Then you don't have to explicitly shut off the backgroundtemplate

Comment: It still seems to leave a white strip at the top for me. I fixed it by setting `\newgeometry`. Funnily enough, if I set `\newgeometry` to 0, I got a white strip at the bottom. I had to trial and error to get the right margins.

Answer (score 18):

An more light-weight approach (no extra packages, no necessity to compile twice) is to set the page-filling image as background template via `\usebackgroundtemplate` and then insert an empty `[plain]` frame.

To restrict the effect of the background changing to a single slide only, we do this inside a TeX group:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        First frame
    \end{frame}
    {
    \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{background.jpg}}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \end{frame}
    }
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        Third frame
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

The following also seems to be working:

```
{
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kernel-panic.png}}
\end{frame}
}
```

Based on a [latex-community post](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=37067&sid=20a28427122005f5c3a1e2289ee8ad46#p37067).

Comment: Simple and powerful. Unlike many other answers, this keep code minimal when overlaying several images on a single frame.

Answer (score 10):

I have been using something like this:

```
\newcommand<>{\fullsizegraphic}[1]{
  \begin{textblock*}{0cm}(-1cm,-3.78cm)
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#1}
  \end{textblock*}
}
```

in the preamble and then just:

```
\begin{frame}
  \fullsizegraphic{monogram.jpg}
\end{frame}
```

But I am not totally satisfied - I still have to fiddle with the numbers to get it right.

Unfortunately I have forgotten where I stole the fullsizegraphic-snippet.

Comment: Works nice, still `\usepackage{textpos}` is needed.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up using following solution:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
% absolute - no need to move block into position
% overlay - remove footer

% Setting default units for textpos simplifies coding a little bit
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

% Place a picture over the slide
\newcommand<>{\fullsizegraphic}[1]{%
  \begin{textblock}{0}(0,0)%
    \only#2{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \fill [black] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        \node[overlay] at (current page.center)
          {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  \end{textblock}%
}
```

And then using it

```
\begin{frame}{My cool three points}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-|alert@1> Point 1
    \item<3-|alert@3> Point 2
    \item<5-|alert@5> Point 3
  \end{itemize}
  \fullsizegraphic<2>{pictures/point1}
  \fullsizegraphic<4>{pictures/point2}
  \fullsizegraphic<6>{pictures/point3}
\end{frame}
```

Setting `keepaspectratio`, `width` and `height` in `\includegraphics` scales your image up to the frame border.

Not used space get filled with black using TiKZ `\fill [black] (...)`

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I use

```
{
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[height = \paperheight, 
                                      width = \paperwidth]{image.jpg}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}
```

I find it more intuitive, easier and it does not require any extra packages or runs.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please elaborate on your answer, not just posting fragments. Please add a screen shot of the result as well

Comment: @Santiago Seems similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3994/36296

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but I think I read that using `\setbeamertemplate` is better than \`usebackgroundtemplate`, due to a beamer package update. TeXstudio, for example, highlights it as a warning.

Comment: And this enables one to write captions onto the picture.

Comment: @Santiago Beamer defines `\usebackgroundtemplate` as `\def\usebackgroundtemplate{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}}`, so internally it is the same. The code highlighting of texstudio is inconsequential for the tex code.

Answer (score 6):

Is the aspect ratio of your image the same as that of your slides?  If not then you'll always get either borders or clipping of the image if you include it without changing its aspect ratio.

You can put `\hspace{-1.2cm}` before your `\includegraphics` command to place the image 1.2 cm to the left of where it would be by default.  Playing with the distance should let you place it right on the edge of the slide.

Answer (score 2):

One could use the fact that beamer columns remove the normal text margins:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{\paperwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```