# How to insert a background image in a beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I want to insert a background image in a beamer frame and use this "frame" as a beamer frame. I want to insert different background images on different frames. Towards this end, I tried

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{../images/crayons.png}}
```

on a specific frame to insert a background image, but I was unsuccessful. Am I missing any package? Or is there a different way of doing this?

I found this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/image-on-full-slide-in-beamer-package) about inserting image but not as a background. In addition to inserting a background image, I also want to add text to the frame. (It is highly likely that I could not understand the questions correctly)

As a side note, if any of you are an Emacs org-mode users, can you please tell me a way to do this in org-beamer. I will be very thankful.

Here is a sample slide code:

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Models}
\label{sec-2_3}


\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{../images/crayons.png}}

\begin{itemize} 
\item choose training data set
\item choose test data set
\item choose model
\item fit on training data set
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: I know most of you can are aware, but http://www.tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2007-March/008035.html is the link from where I got the idea.

Comment: Do you use latex.exe or pdflatex or ?

Comment: I use pdflatex. You can ignore the rest if you are not an Emacs user - I actually use Emacs Org-mode to create an .org file. I user org-import to creater a beamer file. I am sorry if you are not an Emacs user.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[image]

I used images [Sir Isaac Newton](http://jimal-khalili.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/isaac_newton-282x300.jpg) (rename it as newton.jpg) and [Kitten](http://mamaneeds2rant.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/cute-sad-kitten06.jpg) (rename it as kitten.jpg)

The code snippet below is self-explanatory and I compiled using pdflatex.exe because of `.jpg` format.

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}


%Global Background must be put in preamble
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{newton.jpg}%
}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


% Local background must be enclosed by curly braces for grouping.
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kitten.jpg}}%
\begin{frame}{Kitten}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: gosh `\usebackgroundtemplate{}`?  that makes things so easy.  man, i love beamer.

Comment: This doesn't work when using a theme (i.e. Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw).

Comment: after using "...\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kitten.jpg}}%..." how is possible to modify the opacity of the background? thanks!

Comment: @luli nest \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kitten.jpg} in \tikz\node[opacity=0.1]{...}; i.e. \usebackgroundtemplate{\tikz\node[opacity=0.1]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kitten.jpg}};}

Comment: This formulation is no longer functional with more recent versions of TexLive. I am currently on version 2022, `\usebackgroundtemplate{}` has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 66):

Write `\usebackgroundtemplate` before the frame, not within:

```
\end{frame}
% Now we install the new template for the following frames:
{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{crayons}} 
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}}
% Now we install another template, effective from now on:
\usebackgroundtemplate{...}
```

Ensure that `\includegraphics` is able to find the image file, since you used `../images/crayons.png`.

Edit: The `\usebackgroundtemplate` should be enclosed with curly braces along with frame (or frames) which it should affect

Comment: I quick question. If I don't need a background, I use a file name which doesn't exist. I am sure there is a better way of doing this. Can you pls enlighten me again?

Comment: @suncoolsu: Just use an empty argument: `\usebackgroundtemplate{}`.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I don't know if the new syntax was present when you answered this, but from the current point of view `\setbeamertemplate{background}{...}` might be better.

Comment: This doesn't work when using a theme (i.e. Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw).

Comment: How to reset it back to previous background? For example, I have set `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow!20}` at the beginning. After the particular slide, then I use `\usebackgroundtemplate{}`, the background color also reset to white, instead of the `yellow!20`.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Perhaps post it as a new question. You could add a link to here, to show the context.

Comment: This formulation is no longer functional with more recent versions of TexLive. I am currently on version 2022, \usebackgroundtemplate{} has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I just tested it: works with TeX Live 2022 and TeX Live 2023, tested also on TeXlive.net. With \usebackgroundtemplate I get a background image. No problem with today's downvote on this answer of 2010, but your statement is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Content
\end{frame}
}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't do a thing with TexLive 2022.