# Changing the header and footer and title images in a Beamer template

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates

I am looking to add a background image to the title page of Beamer template and also to change the header and footer images in the normal slide.

I have yet to find a template where this would be easy to do and I was wondering where to make a start.

I basically want to replicate corporate slides made in ppt with nice Beamer ones so I can use equations already created in LaTeX.

Sorry if this kind of question breaks some kind of forum guideline...

Comment: You can start looking at: [How to insert a background image in a beamer frame?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7916/1952) and [In beamer, problem positioning images (logo and background) and text in a robust way when creating my own template (title frame and following frames)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80552/1952)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use, I have a custom user template for company colors for the titles blocks...

in preamble

```
    \defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
    {
    \begin{flushright}
    \usebeamercolor{structure}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
    \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
    \bigskip
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
    \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
    \end{flushright}
    }

\title[]{yourtitle}
\subtitle[]{Subtitle}
\author[] {you}
\institute[] {company}
\date[] {tody is \today}
\subject{Subject of presentation}
```

---

Here you define the backgroud of the slides, I use only a custom footer of page width

```
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{%
\vbox to \paperheight{
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{slide} %your picture
    }%
}
```

---

And first slide

```
%--- the titlepage frame -------------------------%
{\usebackgroundtemplate%
{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]
{yourpicture}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
```