# What path can I use to specify content in beamer theme styles?

Tags: beamer, graphics, paths, themes

The author of this [neat theme](http://www.drbunsen.org/designing-a-beamer-template-theme/) posted the source on github, but as the commits state, the background image was thrown in later and not referenced in the style files.

I added a global background template to the main style file, but using `./` as the relative path doesn't work. Is there a relative path for `CURRENT_THEME` that I can use to specify it? Neither the Beamer manual nor any existing questions/answers I found go into path issues about this.

Comment: Does this help?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame

Comment: I actually took a look at that one. No paths are given in the code snippets. I also looked at another theme with a background image, and it turns out they install to `/usr/local/` with a script and use absolute paths in the style file.

Comment: Did you try to copy background image in working folder? (forget `./` in this case)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242236/36296 might help