# Paths of `pgfimages` in beamer templates

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am working on a beamer template for my institute in which I am using `\pgfdeclareimage` for images. I have quite a lot images and logos for different projects/experiments/groups and I organised the files as

> mainfolder/
>  
> -example.tex
>  
> -beamerthememy.sty
>  
> -art/myexample.pdf

Now the problem is how to declare the images. Using

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=.5\paperwidth]{test}{art/myexample.pdf}
```

works for the `.tex` file in the same folder as the `.sty` file and the `art` directory.

But when I put the `.sty` file and the `art` directory inside my `$TEXMFHOME` directory (and the `.tex` file somewhere else) I have to use

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=.5\paperwidth]{test}{myexample.pdf}
```

I there a way to declare the image which works in both cases?

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% works if .tex file is in the same directory as the .sty file and `testdir`
\pgfdeclareimage[width=.5\paperwidth]{test}{art/myexample.pdf}  

% works if .sty file and `textdir` are in my lokal `texmf` folder
%\pgfdeclareimage[width=.5\paperwidth]{test}{myexample.pdf}     

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
         \pgfuseimage{test}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

To make the example minimal I moved `\pgfdeclareimage` from the `.sty` file to the `.tex` file. If you have the feeling, this is too minimal, I will add a .sty file

Comment: Simple workaround: `\IfFileExists{art/example.pdf}{\pdfdeclareimage[...]{test}{art/myexample.pdf}}{\pdfdeclareimage[...]{test}{myexample.pdf}}`, which could of course be further improved by moving this into a macro and  maybe also checking the second path with `\IfFileExists`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `pgfimage...` rather than `graphicx`? You need this if you are declaring masks etc. but otherwise, `graphicx` is recommended.

Comment: @Daniel Great idea! I have to test thoroughly, but it looks, like this might solve my problem. Would you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Well, the TikZ manual recommends using `graphicx` unless you especially need something the `pgfimage...` stuff handles.  Page 1066: 'To be quite frank, LaTeX’s `\includegraphics` is designed better than pgf’s image mechanism. For this
reason, *I recommend that you use the standard image inclusion mechanism of your format*. Thus, LaTeX
users are encouraged to use `\includegraphics` to include images.'

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your quick replay and pointing to the relevant section of the manual. I think "The advantage of this two-phase approach is that, at least for pdf, the image data will only be included once in the file. This can drastically reduce the file size if you use an image repeatedly" is some really big advantage for my project.

Comment: That's not peculiar to TikZ as far as I can tell. If I add an image multiple times with `\includegraphics`, the file size doesn't change more than adding it once. Not even if I use e.g. `scale=.5` the second time. I added the `tiger` image (from the standard distribution) once - 40K. Twice - 40K. Thrice - 40K. Again with `scale=.5` - 40K. Then adding `example-image-a` on top - 44K. Add `example-image-a` again - 44K. The `pgfimage` stuff is just passing things to `\includegraphics` anyway. At least for pdfTeX, it makes no difference to file size.

Comment: I don't know why the manual makes it sound as if the two-stage approach is required for this. Maybe it is out of date?

Comment: *"This can drastically reduce the file size if you use an image repeatedly".* In fact, `\includegraphics`  automatically detects multiple inclusions and [stores the image only once](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139400/how-do-i-use-same-figure-multiple-times/139405#139405) into the resulting PDF.

Comment: @cfr and Daniel: Thanks for the clarification about the filesizes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell, if you pass more than a file name (a path) to `pgfdeclareimage`, `pdflatex` looks just there. Otherwise, it looks for it in the complete search path, which traditionally is specified in the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable.

So a simple solution would be to add `./art` to `TEXINPUTS` and then just use the file name in `pdfdeclareimage`.

However, as this is for a reusable template, you have to keep your users in mind. MikTeX, for instance, handles search paths differently and many users have difficulties to fiddle with environment variables, especially when using some LaTeX-IDE. So For ease of use, I would try to handle this in the template itself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\samdeclareimage}[3][]{%
  % first check local art directory to prefer it over TEXINPUTS paths
  \IfFileExists{./art/#3}{%
    \pgfdeclareimage[#1]{#2}{./art/#3}%
  }{%
    % check if we can found it in TEXINPUTS
    \IfFileExists{#3}{%
      \pgfdeclareimage[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
      \GenericError{}{Theme image #3 not found!}{Consult Sam for all the details, but pressing 'H' might give you the right hint.}{The file '#3' has to be available either in a local 'art' directory or somehwere in your TEXMF tree.}
    }%
  }%
}%

\samdeclareimage[width=.5\paperwidth]{test}{myexample.pdf}  

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
         \pgfuseimage{test}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```