# Beamer: positioning background image in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have been trying for a while to fix the image to the center for the frame, but it is attached to the top. I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
{\usebackgroundtemplate{\centering \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{./Figures/Planck_CMB.jpg}}%
\begin{frame}


\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Someone can help me with it?

Comment: You should give a full MWE...in any case, see the first answer to [How to insert a background image in a beamer frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame)

Comment: I looked into this example, I don't see where it's explained how to position the background image, just how to add it to a single frame..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using a `picture` environment might help:

```
\documentclass[bigger,t]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{
  \usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \begin{picture}(100,220)
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Planck_CMB}
    \end{picture}
  }%
  \begin{frame}
    RIP Stephen Hawking!
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
  text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I didn't know this picture environment in laTex

Comment: Does not move the picture anywhere here…

Comment: @DominikGeorge I does move, at least in vertical direction, which was the necessary for the question. If you have a new question, please open a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In combination with \hspace*{Xcm} before \includegraphics you can move the picture everywhere you like.