# Changing the background color of pdfscreen slides?

Tags: color

How to change background of slides? I used a prepared tex file to prepare my slides. I don't understand which part describes the color of the sildes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{screen}
\margins{0.65in}{0.65in}{0.65in}{0.65in}
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\end{screen}
%\usepackage{pdftricks}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%\changeoverlay
%\overlay{overlay0}
\bottombuttons
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.48, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.3, 0.0}
\definecolor{gray10}{gray}{1.0}
\definecolor{gray30}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.9,0.3,0.0}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.99,0.0,0.99}

\boldmath

\newcommand{\ga}{\Omega_{1}}
\newcommand{\gb}{\Omega_{2}}
\newcommand{\gc}{\Omega_{3}}
\newcommand{\gas}{\Omega_{1s}}
\newcommand{\gbs}{\Omega_{2s}}
\newcommand{\gcs}{\Omega_{3s}}
\newcommand{\gass}{\Omega_{1ss}}
\newcommand{\gbss}{\Omega_{2ss}}
\newcommand{\gcss}{\Omega_{3ss}}
\newcommand{\gasss}{\Omega_{1sss}}
\newcommand{\gbsss}{\Omega_{2sss}}
\newcommand{\gcsss}{\Omega_{3sss}}
\newcommand{\gassss}{\Omega_{1ssss}}
\newcommand{\gbssss}{\Omega_{2ssss}}
\newcommand{\gcssss}{\Omega_{3ssss}}
\newcommand{\lam}{\Lambda}
\newcommand{\lams}{\Lambda_{s}}
\newcommand{\lamss}{\Lambda_{ss}}
\newcommand{\lamsss}{\Lambda_{sss}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\hat{{\bf e}}_{1}}
\newcommand{\eb}{\hat{{\bf e}}_{2}}
\newcommand{\ec}{\hat{{\bf e}}_{3}}
\newcommand{\clbg}{\color{green}}
\newcommand{\tcbg}{\textcolor{green}}
\newcommand{\clb}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\tcb}{\textcolor{blue}}
\newcommand{\clr}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\tcr}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\clbr}{\color{brown}}
\newcommand{\tcbr}{\textcolor{brown}}
\newcommand{\clv}{\color{violet}}
\newcommand{\tcv}{\textcolor{violet}}
\newcommand{\bit}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\eit}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\bs}{\begin{slide}}
\newcommand{\es}{\end{slide}}
\newcommand{\bnc}{\begin{center}}
\newcommand{\enc}{\end{center}}
\newcommand{\bne}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\ene}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\bnt}{\begin{tabular}}
\newcommand{\ent}{\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\ast$}

%-------Slide 1 Opening slide------% 
\begin{slide} 
\sffamily

\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\color{blue}
\LARGE {SUPERSYMMETRY AND ITS REPRESENTATIONS
}
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\textcolor{red}
{\LARGE \bf  SWATHI T S }\\
~\\
\vspace{2cm}
{\bf  MSc Project}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\textcolor{blue}{Department of Physics, Union Christian College}\\
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
%\begin{center}
%\textcolor{blue}
%\end{center}
\vspace{3.0cm}
\begin{flushleft}
\textcolor{blue}
{\small \LaTeX$2_{\varepsilon}$}
\end{flushleft}
\end{slide} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, people preferrably use `beamer` these days.

Comment: You probably want to use the `beamer` documentclass for slides.  There you can easily insert a background, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame

Comment: `\backgroundcolor{black}`

Comment: i am only learning use latex and the presentation has to be ready by tommorow. So i used a prepared slide and m editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the command `\backgroundcolor{some colour}`in the preamble.

I replace `color` loading with the more powerful `xcolor` package and options `[svgnames, table]`.

Just a comment aside: all your command and ccolour definitions should go to the preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{screen}
\margins{0.65in}{0.65in}{0.65in}{0.65in}
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\end{screen}
%\usepackage{pdftricks}

 \backgroundcolor{BlanchedAlmond}

%\changeoverlay
%\overlay{overlay0}
\bottombuttons
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.48, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.3, 0.0}
\definecolor{gray10}{gray}{1.0}
\definecolor{gray30}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.9,0.3,0.0}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.99,0.0,0.99}

\boldmath

\newcommand{\ga}{\Omega_{1}}
\newcommand{\gb}{\Omega_{2}}
\newcommand{\gc}{\Omega_{3}}
\newcommand{\gas}{\Omega_{1s}}
\newcommand{\gbs}{\Omega_{2s}}
\newcommand{\gcs}{\Omega_{3s}}
\newcommand{\gass}{\Omega_{1ss}}
\newcommand{\gbss}{\Omega_{2ss}}
\newcommand{\gcss}{\Omega_{3ss}}
\newcommand{\gasss}{\Omega_{1sss}}
\newcommand{\gbsss}{\Omega_{2sss}}
\newcommand{\gcsss}{\Omega_{3sss}}
\newcommand{\gassss}{\Omega_{1ssss}}
\newcommand{\gbssss}{\Omega_{2ssss}}
\newcommand{\gcssss}{\Omega_{3ssss}}
\newcommand{\lam}{\Lambda}
\newcommand{\lams}{\Lambda_{s}}
\newcommand{\lamss}{\Lambda_{ss}}
\newcommand{\lamsss}{\Lambda_{sss}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\hat{{\bf e}}_{1}}
\newcommand{\eb}{\hat{{\bf e}}_{2}}
\newcommand{\ec}{\hat{{\bf e}}_{3}}
\newcommand{\clbg}{\color{green}}
\newcommand{\tcbg}{\textcolor{green}}
\newcommand{\clb}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\tcb}{\textcolor{blue}}
\newcommand{\clr}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\tcr}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\clbr}{\color{brown}}
\newcommand{\tcbr}{\textcolor{brown}}
\newcommand{\clv}{\color{violet}}
\newcommand{\tcv}{\textcolor{violet}}
\newcommand{\bit}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\eit}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\bs}{\begin{slide}}
\newcommand{\es}{\end{slide}}
\newcommand{\bnc}{\begin{center}}
\newcommand{\enc}{\end{center}}
\newcommand{\bne}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\ene}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\bnt}{\begin{tabular}}
\newcommand{\ent}{\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\ast$}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%-------Slide 1 Opening slide------%
\begin{slide}
\sffamily

\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\color{blue}
\LARGE {SUPERSYMMETRY AND ITS REPRESENTATIONS
}
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\textcolor{red}
{\LARGE \bf SWATHI T S }\\
~\\
\vspace{2cm}
{\bf MSc Project}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\textcolor{blue}{Department of Physics, Union Christian College}\\
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\vspace{3.0cm}
\begin{flushleft}
\textcolor{blue}
{\small \LaTeX$2_{\varepsilon}$}
\end{flushleft}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

[image]