# How to overlay the fullscreen picture with box of tex

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, overlays, block, includegraphics

I found it very impressed with this display style of the author. My question is how to overlay the fullscreen picture with box of tex ? Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a background image in a beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame)

Comment: @HenriMenke Not really, the hard part is not the image but the semi-transparent block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[at=(current page.center)]{
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Leonardo_da_vinci,_Drawings_of_Water_Lifting_Devices}
        };
        \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}
        \node[at=(current page.center)]{
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.5cm,wd=.8\paperwidth]{title}%
                \centering
                \pgfsetfillopacity{1}%
                \LARGE
                Your text
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(using https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Leonardo_da_vinci,_Drawings_of_Water_Lifting_Devices.jpg)

Comment: How to put the block of text at the bottom of the page ?

Comment: @NguyenThy Change the position in `\node[at=(current page.center)]{` If it should be at the bottom: `current page.south`