# How to insert a background image at the bottom of a beamer frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I am using the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7919/254236) i.e.

```
% Local background must be enclosed by curly braces for grouping.
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kitten.jpg}}%
\begin{frame}{Kitten}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}
```

I only know how to force an image to be in the bottom by using `\begin{figure}[b]\end{figure}` but if I use that I receive an error. My attempt looks like this:

```
% Local background must be enclosed by curly braces for grouping.
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\begin{figure}[b]\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kitten.jpg}\end{figure}}%
\begin{frame}{Kitten}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}
```

I would like to find a way of positioning the image of the background at the bottom.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Add the package `tikz` and use `xshift` and `yshift` to move the image.
[image: e]

There are many other alternatives but this one has a very easy to understand code.

In the first frame the center of the image (A) coincides with the center of the frame, so `xshift` and `yshift` are equal to `0cm`.

In the second frame the image (B) --with a height of `0.5\paperheight`-- is shifted `0.25\paperheight` down and touches the bottom.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{tikz} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text not needed

\begin{document}    
    {\usebackgroundtemplate{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
                                }%
    
        \begin{frame}{Center}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3
            \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}
    }
    
        {\usebackgroundtemplate{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=-0.25\paperheight] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
                }%
        
        \begin{frame}{Bottom}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3
            \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}
    }
    
    {\usebackgroundtemplate{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node [xshift=-0.1\paperheight,yshift= 0.12\paperheight] at (current page.south east){\includegraphics[height=0.16\paperheight, keepaspectratio]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    
    \begin{frame}{Bottom right}
    \kant[9] 
    \end{frame}
        }   

    \end{document}
```

[image: d]

Here, the center of a smaller image is set in the lower right corner of the frame, so it needs to be moved to the left and up.

See more examples in [Positioning relative to page in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89592/161015)

Comment: Finding the desired position would be easier if you add an anchor to the node as well. For example, `\node [anchor=south east,inner sep=0] at (current page.south east){\includegraphics[width=0.25\paperheight]{example-image-c}};`

Comment: @erik  You are right, but I do not know if the OP is familiar with `tikz`.  With movements in units of image height should be enough as a starting point.