# How to insert a Tikz stock price process in Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Does anyone know how I can mimic a "stock price process" by means of a Tikz picture and place this on the background of a beamer title page presentation. I have some boiler code, but I cannot get the fit right:

```
\definecolor{vua}{RGB}{106,153,218}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1.1,remember picture,overlay,scale=4.1,yshift=-1.6cm,xshift=-1.1cm]
\shadedraw[vua,top color=vua!30!white, bottom color=white,ultra thick] (0.4235,7.2111) .. controls (0.4185,7.1960) and (0.4609,7.2095) .. (0.4817,7.2296) .. controls (0.5018,7.2491) and (0.5225,7.2535) .. (0.5329,7.2404) .. controls (0.5363,7.2361) and (0.5454,7.2084) .. (0.5531,7.1788) .. controls (0.5721,7.1057) and (0.5742,7.1033) .. (0.5959,7.1293) .. controls (0.6153,7.1526) and (0.6228,7.1515) .. (0.6374,7.1233) .. controls (0.6426,7.1132) and (0.6508,7.1050) .. (0.6555,7.1050) .. controls (0.6603,7.1050) and (0.6781,7.1206) .. (0.6952,7.1397) .. controls (0.7122,7.1588) and (0.7276,7.1721) .. (0.7293,7.1693) .. controls (0.7310,7.1664) and (0.7385,7.1277) .. (0.7459,7.0832) .. controls (0.7641,6.9739) and (0.7709,6.9684) .. (0.7954,7.0434) .. controls (0.8028,7.0660) and (0.8171,7.0975) .. (0.8272,7.1134) .. controls (0.8423,7.1373) and (0.8487,7.1423) .. (0.8642,7.1423) .. controls (0.8850,7.1423) and (0.8931,7.1522) .. (0.9119,7.2006) .. controls (0.9323,7.2533) and (0.9506,7.2453) .. (0.9764,7.1723) .. controls (0.9850,7.1477) and (0.9949,7.1267) .. (0.9984,7.1256) .. controls (1.0018,7.1245) and (1.0123,7.1362) .. (1.0216,7.1517) .. controls (1.0309,7.1671) and (1.0409,7.1797) .. (1.0439,7.1797) .. controls (1.0513,7.1797) and (1.0682,7.1604) .. (1.0912,7.1256) .. controls (1.1062,7.1028) and (1.1167,7.0944) .. (1.1394,7.0867) .. controls (1.1742,7.0750) and (1.1917,7.0601) .. (1.2079,7.0282) .. controls (1.2157,7.0130) and (1.2277,7.0012) .. (1.2411,6.9956) .. controls (1.2555,6.9896) and (1.2686,6.9760) .. (1.2826,6.9526) .. controls (1.2963,6.9298) and (1.3091,6.9163) .. (1.3213,6.9121) .. controls (1.3431,6.9045) and (1.3507,6.9094) .. (1.3700,6.9439) .. controls (1.3837,6.9683) and (1.3993,6.9744) .. (1.4111,6.9602) .. controls (1.4160,6.9543) and (1.4498,6.8007) .. (1.4498,6.7843) .. controls (1.4498,6.7741) and (1.4676,6.7838) .. (1.4737,6.7972) .. controls (1.4778,6.8061) and (1.4843,6.8122) .. (1.4882,6.8109) .. controls (1.4922,6.8096) and (1.5028,6.7705) .. (1.5118,6.7241) .. controls (1.5257,6.6530) and (1.5313,6.6359) .. (1.5474,6.6155) .. controls (1.5592,6.6006) and (1.5741,6.5672) .. (1.5861,6.5290) .. controls (1.6045,6.4700) and (1.6312,6.4263) .. (1.6488,6.4263) .. controls (1.6522,6.4263) and (1.6633,6.4427) .. (1.6735,6.4628) .. controls (1.6901,6.4957) and (1.6949,6.5003) .. (1.7218,6.5092) .. controls (1.7450,6.5169) and (1.7533,6.5174) .. (1.7587,6.5116) .. controls (1.7625,6.5075) and (1.7707,6.4789) .. (1.7768,6.4481) .. controls (1.7914,6.3750) and (1.7940,6.3702) .. (1.8204,6.3702) .. controls (1.8385,6.3702) and (1.8444,6.3664) .. (1.8582,6.3455) .. controls (1.8764,6.3181) and (1.9089,6.3063) .. (1.9301,6.3196) .. controls (1.9492,6.3315) and (1.9534,6.3280) .. (1.9637,6.2909) .. controls (1.9841,6.2177) and (1.9859,6.2143) .. (2.0110,6.1985) .. controls (2.0402,6.1801) and (2.0635,6.1452) .. (2.0849,6.0881) .. controls (2.0934,6.0652) and (2.1039,6.0465) .. (2.1081,6.0465) .. controls (2.1124,6.0465) and (2.1199,6.0563) .. (2.1249,6.0683) .. controls (2.1299,6.0802) and (2.1369,6.0900) .. (2.1405,6.0900) .. controls (2.1474,6.0900) and (2.1480,6.0880) .. (2.1643,6.0092) .. controls (2.1788,5.9388) and (2.1902,5.9357) .. (2.2058,5.9980) .. controls (2.2195,6.0526) and (2.2375,6.0963) .. (2.2462,6.0963) .. controls (2.2565,6.0963) and (2.2634,6.0780) .. (2.2776,6.0122) .. controls (2.2850,5.9780) and (2.2937,5.9473) .. (2.2969,5.9441) .. controls (2.3057,5.9352) and (2.3363,5.9677) .. (2.3590,6.0104) .. controls (2.3774,6.0449) and (2.3803,6.0475) .. (2.3963,6.0443) .. controls (2.4066,6.0422) and (2.4161,6.0439) .. (2.4195,6.0483) .. controls (2.4309,6.0633) and (2.4647,6.2138) .. (2.4771,6.3049) .. controls (2.4947,6.4335) and (2.4923,6.4263) .. (2.5167,6.4263) .. controls (2.5371,6.4263) and (2.5830,6.4518) .. (2.6031,6.4744) .. controls (2.6085,6.4805) and (2.6189,6.5057) .. (2.6262,6.5306) .. controls (2.6335,6.5554) and (2.6419,6.5757) .. (2.6448,6.5757) .. controls (2.6477,6.5757) and (2.6562,6.5596) .. (2.6638,6.5399) .. controls (2.6714,6.5202) and (2.6854,6.4859) .. (2.6949,6.4636) .. controls (2.7132,6.4211) and (2.7342,6.3482) .. (2.7642,6.2239) .. controls (2.7870,6.1292) and (2.7895,6.1238) .. (2.8125,6.1192) .. controls (2.8301,6.1157) and (2.8324,6.1117) .. (2.8482,6.0591) .. controls (2.8664,5.9986) and (2.8753,5.9908) .. (2.8912,6.0216) .. controls (2.8965,6.0318) and (2.9034,6.0402) .. (2.9065,6.0402) .. controls (2.9127,6.0402) and (2.9129,6.0395) .. (2.9313,5.9722) .. controls (2.9438,5.9264) and (2.9677,5.8908) .. (2.9859,5.8908) .. controls (2.9905,5.8908) and (2.9974,5.8985) .. (3.0013,5.9079) .. controls (3.0452,6.0142) and (3.0542,6.0157) .. (3.0841,5.9219) .. controls (3.1023,5.8650) and (3.1316,5.8020) .. (3.1528,5.7742) .. controls (3.1664,5.7564) and (3.1772,5.7309) .. (3.1860,5.6956) .. controls (3.2033,5.6266) and (3.2098,5.6106) .. (3.2203,5.6106) .. controls (3.2291,5.6106) and (3.2649,5.6477) .. (3.2778,5.6701) .. controls (3.2845,5.6816) and (3.2848,5.6816) .. (3.2911,5.6696) .. controls (3.2947,5.6628) and (3.3036,5.6281) .. (3.3108,5.5924) .. controls (3.3181,5.5567) and (3.3252,5.5263) .. (3.3267,5.5248) .. controls (3.3338,5.5177) and (3.3467,5.5367) .. (3.3718,5.5913) .. controls (3.4131,5.6813) and (3.4122,5.6798) .. (3.4261,5.6778) .. controls (3.4362,5.6764) and (3.4428,5.6637) .. (3.4580,5.6168) .. controls (3.4750,5.5644) and (3.4794,5.5567) .. (3.4969,5.5489) .. controls (3.5132,5.5416) and (3.5187,5.5333) .. (3.5292,5.5009) .. controls (3.5362,5.4793) and (3.5420,5.4567) .. (3.5421,5.4505) .. controls (3.5423,5.4365) and (3.5526,5.4236) .. (3.5751,5.4092) .. controls (3.5981,5.3945) and (3.6061,5.3984) .. (3.6164,5.4295) .. controls (3.6211,5.4437) and (3.6279,5.4543) .. (3.6316,5.4530) .. controls (3.6353,5.4518) and (3.6442,5.4030) .. (3.6515,5.3443) .. controls (3.6588,5.2857) and (3.6664,5.2334) .. (3.6685,5.2281) .. controls (3.6756,5.2095) and (3.6841,5.2185) .. (3.6975,5.2587) .. controls (3.7049,5.2810) and (3.7133,5.3006) .. (3.7162,5.3024) .. controls (3.7191,5.3042) and (3.7266,5.2990) .. (3.7330,5.2910) .. controls (3.7468,5.2734) and (3.7669,5.2619) .. (3.7838,5.2619) .. controls (3.7913,5.2619) and (3.8116,5.2792) .. (3.8352,5.3058) .. controls (3.8942,5.3721) and (3.8949,5.3715) .. (3.9191,5.2277) .. controls (3.9300,5.1626) and (3.9393,5.1081) .. (3.9397,5.1066) .. controls (3.9401,5.1052) and (3.9485,5.1117) .. (3.9584,5.1212) .. controls (3.9683,5.1307) and (3.9778,5.1361) .. (3.9795,5.1332) .. controls (3.9812,5.1304) and (3.9875,5.1098) .. (3.9934,5.0876) .. controls (3.9994,5.0653) and (4.0150,5.0257) .. (4.0281,4.9995) .. controls (4.0487,4.9583) and (4.0541,4.9378) .. (4.0684,4.8470) .. controls (4.0774,4.7892) and (4.0859,4.7385) .. (4.0871,4.7342) .. controls (4.0918,4.7184) and (4.1074,4.7271) .. (4.1169,4.7508) .. controls (4.1222,4.7642) and (4.1294,4.7769) .. (4.1329,4.7790) .. controls (4.1363,4.7812) and (4.1537,4.7536) .. (4.1718,4.7173) .. controls (4.1898,4.6812) and (4.2077,4.6517) .. (4.2116,4.6517) .. controls (4.2160,4.6517) and (4.2243,4.6861) .. (4.2330,4.7404) .. controls (4.2408,4.7892) and (4.2498,4.8320) .. (4.2530,4.8354) .. controls (4.2568,4.8395) and (4.2628,4.8368) .. (4.2703,4.8276) .. controls (4.2861,4.8083) and (4.2936,4.8100) .. (4.3042,4.8354) .. controls (4.3123,4.8546) and (4.3264,4.8655) .. (4.3264,4.8524) .. controls (4.3264,4.8417) and (4.3572,4.6998) .. (4.3602,4.6968) .. controls (4.3619,4.6950) and (4.3704,4.6982) .. (4.3789,4.7038) .. controls (4.3875,4.7094) and (4.3959,4.7140) .. (4.3977,4.7140) .. controls (4.3995,4.7140) and (4.4079,4.7002) .. (4.4165,4.6833) .. controls (4.4340,4.6487) and (4.4427,4.6410) .. (4.4527,4.6510) .. controls (4.4762,4.6745) and (4.4995,4.6339) .. (4.5342,4.5085) .. controls (4.5590,4.4189) and (4.6162,4.2788) .. (4.6302,4.2735) .. controls (4.6489,4.2663) and (4.6789,4.3095) .. (4.6911,4.3614) .. controls (4.6973,4.3877) and (4.7052,4.4082) .. (4.7087,4.4070) .. controls (4.7122,4.4058) and (4.7209,4.3813) .. (4.7279,4.3524) .. controls (4.7355,4.3212) and (4.7498,4.2848) .. (4.7632,4.2626) .. controls (4.7756,4.2420) and (4.7917,4.2133) .. (4.7990,4.1987) .. controls (4.8080,4.1809) and (4.8198,4.1687) .. (4.8353,4.1614) .. controls (4.8552,4.1519) and (4.8606,4.1443) .. (4.8759,4.1041) .. controls (4.8971,4.0484) and (4.9298,4.0058) .. (4.9534,4.0030) .. controls (4.9661,4.0015) and (4.9748,3.9930) .. (4.9897,3.9676) .. controls (5.0005,3.9491) and (5.0161,3.9303) .. (5.0243,3.9258) .. controls (5.0551,3.9087) and (5.0585,3.9126) .. (5.0762,3.9839) .. controls (5.0854,4.0207) and (5.1022,4.0719) .. (5.1137,4.0976) .. controls (5.1415,4.1600) and (5.1449,4.1752) .. (5.1605,4.3093) .. controls (5.1678,4.3726) and (5.1807,4.4679) .. (5.1891,4.5210) .. controls (5.2379,4.8307) and (5.2469,4.8744) .. (5.2722,4.9245) .. controls (5.2821,4.9440) and (5.2948,4.9837) .. (5.3006,5.0129) .. controls (5.3181,5.1018) and (5.3218,5.1060) .. (5.3382,5.0565) .. controls (5.3505,5.0194) and (5.3556,5.0153) .. (5.3738,5.0281) .. controls (5.3815,5.0334) and (5.3907,5.0378) .. (5.3944,5.0378) .. controls (5.3981,5.0378) and (5.4147,5.0152) .. (5.4314,4.9877) .. controls (5.4480,4.9602) and (5.4641,4.9361) .. (5.4670,4.9343) .. controls (5.4781,4.9275) and (5.5104,4.9397) .. (5.5165,4.9530) .. controls (5.5199,4.9606) and (5.5290,5.0029) .. (5.5366,5.0470) .. controls (5.5445,5.0924) and (5.5537,5.1283) .. (5.5579,5.1297) .. controls (5.5620,5.1310) and (5.5700,5.1276) .. (5.5756,5.1219) .. controls (5.5812,5.1163) and (5.5879,5.1140) .. (5.5905,5.1168) .. controls (5.5930,5.1195) and (5.6027,5.1667) .. (5.6119,5.2214) .. controls (5.6332,5.3474) and (5.6318,5.3429) .. (5.6501,5.3429) .. controls (5.6719,5.3429) and (5.6733,5.3476) .. (5.6966,5.4970) .. controls (5.7041,5.5457) and (5.7125,5.5531) .. (5.7298,5.5267) -- (current page.south east) -- (current page.south west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that it should be some kind of background: Do you want something like this?

You essentially need to scale the "meaningful part" of the curve (which is everything between 0.4235cm and 5.7298cm) to the width of the paper. Thus, you would calculate `\paperwidth/(5.7298cm-0.4235cm)` and scale the `tikzpicture` accordingly. Then, you need to shift the first coordinate of the curve, which is `(0.4235,7.2111)` to the left page margin.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{vua}{RGB}{106,153,218}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, scale={\paperwidth/(5.7298cm-0.4235cm)}, shift={(current page.north west)}]
        \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.4235cm,3.75cm)}, yscale=-1]
            \shadedraw [vua,top color=vua!30!white, bottom color=white, thick]
(0.4235,7.2111) .. controls (0.4185,7.1960) and (0.4609,7.2095) .. (0.4817,7.2296) 
                .. controls (0.5018,7.2491) and (0.5225,7.2535) .. (0.5329,7.2404) 
                .. controls (0.5363,7.2361) and (0.5454,7.2084) .. (0.5531,7.1788) 
                .. controls (0.5721,7.1057) and (0.5742,7.1033) .. (0.5959,7.1293) 
                .. controls (0.6153,7.1526) and (0.6228,7.1515) .. (0.6374,7.1233) 
                .. controls (0.6426,7.1132) and (0.6508,7.1050) .. (0.6555,7.1050) 
                .. controls (0.6603,7.1050) and (0.6781,7.1206) .. (0.6952,7.1397) 
                .. controls (0.7122,7.1588) and (0.7276,7.1721) .. (0.7293,7.1693) 
                .. controls (0.7310,7.1664) and (0.7385,7.1277) .. (0.7459,7.0832) 
                .. controls (0.7641,6.9739) and (0.7709,6.9684) .. (0.7954,7.0434) 
                .. controls (0.8028,7.0660) and (0.8171,7.0975) .. (0.8272,7.1134) 
                .. controls (0.8423,7.1373) and (0.8487,7.1423) .. (0.8642,7.1423) 
                .. controls (0.8850,7.1423) and (0.8931,7.1522) .. (0.9119,7.2006) 
                .. controls (0.9323,7.2533) and (0.9506,7.2453) .. (0.9764,7.1723) 
                .. controls (0.9850,7.1477) and (0.9949,7.1267) .. (0.9984,7.1256) 
                .. controls (1.0018,7.1245) and (1.0123,7.1362) .. (1.0216,7.1517) 
                .. controls (1.0309,7.1671) and (1.0409,7.1797) .. (1.0439,7.1797) 
                .. controls (1.0513,7.1797) and (1.0682,7.1604) .. (1.0912,7.1256) 
                .. controls (1.1062,7.1028) and (1.1167,7.0944) .. (1.1394,7.0867) 
                .. controls (1.1742,7.0750) and (1.1917,7.0601) .. (1.2079,7.0282) 
                .. controls (1.2157,7.0130) and (1.2277,7.0012) .. (1.2411,6.9956) 
                .. controls (1.2555,6.9896) and (1.2686,6.9760) .. (1.2826,6.9526) 
                .. controls (1.2963,6.9298) and (1.3091,6.9163) .. (1.3213,6.9121) 
                .. controls (1.3431,6.9045) and (1.3507,6.9094) .. (1.3700,6.9439) 
                .. controls (1.3837,6.9683) and (1.3993,6.9744) .. (1.4111,6.9602) 
                .. controls (1.4160,6.9543) and (1.4498,6.8007) .. (1.4498,6.7843) 
                .. controls (1.4498,6.7741) and (1.4676,6.7838) .. (1.4737,6.7972) 
                .. controls (1.4778,6.8061) and (1.4843,6.8122) .. (1.4882,6.8109) 
                .. controls (1.4922,6.8096) and (1.5028,6.7705) .. (1.5118,6.7241) 
                .. controls (1.5257,6.6530) and (1.5313,6.6359) .. (1.5474,6.6155) 
                .. controls (1.5592,6.6006) and (1.5741,6.5672) .. (1.5861,6.5290) 
                .. controls (1.6045,6.4700) and (1.6312,6.4263) .. (1.6488,6.4263) 
                .. controls (1.6522,6.4263) and (1.6633,6.4427) .. (1.6735,6.4628) 
                .. controls (1.6901,6.4957) and (1.6949,6.5003) .. (1.7218,6.5092) 
                .. controls (1.7450,6.5169) and (1.7533,6.5174) .. (1.7587,6.5116) 
                .. controls (1.7625,6.5075) and (1.7707,6.4789) .. (1.7768,6.4481) 
                .. controls (1.7914,6.3750) and (1.7940,6.3702) .. (1.8204,6.3702) 
                .. controls (1.8385,6.3702) and (1.8444,6.3664) .. (1.8582,6.3455) 
                .. controls (1.8764,6.3181) and (1.9089,6.3063) .. (1.9301,6.3196) 
                .. controls (1.9492,6.3315) and (1.9534,6.3280) .. (1.9637,6.2909) 
                .. controls (1.9841,6.2177) and (1.9859,6.2143) .. (2.0110,6.1985) 
                .. controls (2.0402,6.1801) and (2.0635,6.1452) .. (2.0849,6.0881) 
                .. controls (2.0934,6.0652) and (2.1039,6.0465) .. (2.1081,6.0465) 
                .. controls (2.1124,6.0465) and (2.1199,6.0563) .. (2.1249,6.0683) 
                .. controls (2.1299,6.0802) and (2.1369,6.0900) .. (2.1405,6.0900) 
                .. controls (2.1474,6.0900) and (2.1480,6.0880) .. (2.1643,6.0092) 
                .. controls (2.1788,5.9388) and (2.1902,5.9357) .. (2.2058,5.9980) 
                .. controls (2.2195,6.0526) and (2.2375,6.0963) .. (2.2462,6.0963) 
                .. controls (2.2565,6.0963) and (2.2634,6.0780) .. (2.2776,6.0122) 
                .. controls (2.2850,5.9780) and (2.2937,5.9473) .. (2.2969,5.9441) 
                .. controls (2.3057,5.9352) and (2.3363,5.9677) .. (2.3590,6.0104) 
                .. controls (2.3774,6.0449) and (2.3803,6.0475) .. (2.3963,6.0443) 
                .. controls (2.4066,6.0422) and (2.4161,6.0439) .. (2.4195,6.0483) 
                .. controls (2.4309,6.0633) and (2.4647,6.2138) .. (2.4771,6.3049) 
                .. controls (2.4947,6.4335) and (2.4923,6.4263) .. (2.5167,6.4263) 
                .. controls (2.5371,6.4263) and (2.5830,6.4518) .. (2.6031,6.4744) 
                .. controls (2.6085,6.4805) and (2.6189,6.5057) .. (2.6262,6.5306) 
                .. controls (2.6335,6.5554) and (2.6419,6.5757) .. (2.6448,6.5757) 
                .. controls (2.6477,6.5757) and (2.6562,6.5596) .. (2.6638,6.5399) 
                .. controls (2.6714,6.5202) and (2.6854,6.4859) .. (2.6949,6.4636) 
                .. controls (2.7132,6.4211) and (2.7342,6.3482) .. (2.7642,6.2239) 
                .. controls (2.7870,6.1292) and (2.7895,6.1238) .. (2.8125,6.1192) 
                .. controls (2.8301,6.1157) and (2.8324,6.1117) .. (2.8482,6.0591) 
                .. controls (2.8664,5.9986) and (2.8753,5.9908) .. (2.8912,6.0216) 
                .. controls (2.8965,6.0318) and (2.9034,6.0402) .. (2.9065,6.0402) 
                .. controls (2.9127,6.0402) and (2.9129,6.0395) .. (2.9313,5.9722) 
                .. controls (2.9438,5.9264) and (2.9677,5.8908) .. (2.9859,5.8908) 
                .. controls (2.9905,5.8908) and (2.9974,5.8985) .. (3.0013,5.9079) 
                .. controls (3.0452,6.0142) and (3.0542,6.0157) .. (3.0841,5.9219) 
                .. controls (3.1023,5.8650) and (3.1316,5.8020) .. (3.1528,5.7742) 
                .. controls (3.1664,5.7564) and (3.1772,5.7309) .. (3.1860,5.6956) 
                .. controls (3.2033,5.6266) and (3.2098,5.6106) .. (3.2203,5.6106) 
                .. controls (3.2291,5.6106) and (3.2649,5.6477) .. (3.2778,5.6701) 
                .. controls (3.2845,5.6816) and (3.2848,5.6816) .. (3.2911,5.6696) 
                .. controls (3.2947,5.6628) and (3.3036,5.6281) .. (3.3108,5.5924) 
                .. controls (3.3181,5.5567) and (3.3252,5.5263) .. (3.3267,5.5248) 
                .. controls (3.3338,5.5177) and (3.3467,5.5367) .. (3.3718,5.5913) 
                .. controls (3.4131,5.6813) and (3.4122,5.6798) .. (3.4261,5.6778) 
                .. controls (3.4362,5.6764) and (3.4428,5.6637) .. (3.4580,5.6168) 
                .. controls (3.4750,5.5644) and (3.4794,5.5567) .. (3.4969,5.5489) 
                .. controls (3.5132,5.5416) and (3.5187,5.5333) .. (3.5292,5.5009) 
                .. controls (3.5362,5.4793) and (3.5420,5.4567) .. (3.5421,5.4505) 
                .. controls (3.5423,5.4365) and (3.5526,5.4236) .. (3.5751,5.4092) 
                .. controls (3.5981,5.3945) and (3.6061,5.3984) .. (3.6164,5.4295) 
                .. controls (3.6211,5.4437) and (3.6279,5.4543) .. (3.6316,5.4530) 
                .. controls (3.6353,5.4518) and (3.6442,5.4030) .. (3.6515,5.3443) 
                .. controls (3.6588,5.2857) and (3.6664,5.2334) .. (3.6685,5.2281) 
                .. controls (3.6756,5.2095) and (3.6841,5.2185) .. (3.6975,5.2587) 
                .. controls (3.7049,5.2810) and (3.7133,5.3006) .. (3.7162,5.3024) 
                .. controls (3.7191,5.3042) and (3.7266,5.2990) .. (3.7330,5.2910) 
                .. controls (3.7468,5.2734) and (3.7669,5.2619) .. (3.7838,5.2619) 
                .. controls (3.7913,5.2619) and (3.8116,5.2792) .. (3.8352,5.3058) 
                .. controls (3.8942,5.3721) and (3.8949,5.3715) .. (3.9191,5.2277) 
                .. controls (3.9300,5.1626) and (3.9393,5.1081) .. (3.9397,5.1066) 
                .. controls (3.9401,5.1052) and (3.9485,5.1117) .. (3.9584,5.1212) 
                .. controls (3.9683,5.1307) and (3.9778,5.1361) .. (3.9795,5.1332) 
                .. controls (3.9812,5.1304) and (3.9875,5.1098) .. (3.9934,5.0876) 
                .. controls (3.9994,5.0653) and (4.0150,5.0257) .. (4.0281,4.9995) 
                .. controls (4.0487,4.9583) and (4.0541,4.9378) .. (4.0684,4.8470) 
                .. controls (4.0774,4.7892) and (4.0859,4.7385) .. (4.0871,4.7342) 
                .. controls (4.0918,4.7184) and (4.1074,4.7271) .. (4.1169,4.7508) 
                .. controls (4.1222,4.7642) and (4.1294,4.7769) .. (4.1329,4.7790) 
                .. controls (4.1363,4.7812) and (4.1537,4.7536) .. (4.1718,4.7173) 
                .. controls (4.1898,4.6812) and (4.2077,4.6517) .. (4.2116,4.6517) 
                .. controls (4.2160,4.6517) and (4.2243,4.6861) .. (4.2330,4.7404) 
                .. controls (4.2408,4.7892) and (4.2498,4.8320) .. (4.2530,4.8354) 
                .. controls (4.2568,4.8395) and (4.2628,4.8368) .. (4.2703,4.8276) 
                .. controls (4.2861,4.8083) and (4.2936,4.8100) .. (4.3042,4.8354) 
                .. controls (4.3123,4.8546) and (4.3264,4.8655) .. (4.3264,4.8524) 
                .. controls (4.3264,4.8417) and (4.3572,4.6998) .. (4.3602,4.6968) 
                .. controls (4.3619,4.6950) and (4.3704,4.6982) .. (4.3789,4.7038) 
                .. controls (4.3875,4.7094) and (4.3959,4.7140) .. (4.3977,4.7140) 
                .. controls (4.3995,4.7140) and (4.4079,4.7002) .. (4.4165,4.6833) 
                .. controls (4.4340,4.6487) and (4.4427,4.6410) .. (4.4527,4.6510) 
                .. controls (4.4762,4.6745) and (4.4995,4.6339) .. (4.5342,4.5085) 
                .. controls (4.5590,4.4189) and (4.6162,4.2788) .. (4.6302,4.2735) 
                .. controls (4.6489,4.2663) and (4.6789,4.3095) .. (4.6911,4.3614) 
                .. controls (4.6973,4.3877) and (4.7052,4.4082) .. (4.7087,4.4070) 
                .. controls (4.7122,4.4058) and (4.7209,4.3813) .. (4.7279,4.3524) 
                .. controls (4.7355,4.3212) and (4.7498,4.2848) .. (4.7632,4.2626) 
                .. controls (4.7756,4.2420) and (4.7917,4.2133) .. (4.7990,4.1987) 
                .. controls (4.8080,4.1809) and (4.8198,4.1687) .. (4.8353,4.1614) 
                .. controls (4.8552,4.1519) and (4.8606,4.1443) .. (4.8759,4.1041) 
                .. controls (4.8971,4.0484) and (4.9298,4.0058) .. (4.9534,4.0030) 
                .. controls (4.9661,4.0015) and (4.9748,3.9930) .. (4.9897,3.9676) 
                .. controls (5.0005,3.9491) and (5.0161,3.9303) .. (5.0243,3.9258) 
                .. controls (5.0551,3.9087) and (5.0585,3.9126) .. (5.0762,3.9839) 
                .. controls (5.0854,4.0207) and (5.1022,4.0719) .. (5.1137,4.0976) 
                .. controls (5.1415,4.1600) and (5.1449,4.1752) .. (5.1605,4.3093) 
                .. controls (5.1678,4.3726) and (5.1807,4.4679) .. (5.1891,4.5210) 
                .. controls (5.2379,4.8307) and (5.2469,4.8744) .. (5.2722,4.9245) 
                .. controls (5.2821,4.9440) and (5.2948,4.9837) .. (5.3006,5.0129) 
                .. controls (5.3181,5.1018) and (5.3218,5.1060) .. (5.3382,5.0565) 
                .. controls (5.3505,5.0194) and (5.3556,5.0153) .. (5.3738,5.0281) 
                .. controls (5.3815,5.0334) and (5.3907,5.0378) .. (5.3944,5.0378) 
                .. controls (5.3981,5.0378) and (5.4147,5.0152) .. (5.4314,4.9877) 
                .. controls (5.4480,4.9602) and (5.4641,4.9361) .. (5.4670,4.9343) 
                .. controls (5.4781,4.9275) and (5.5104,4.9397) .. (5.5165,4.9530) 
                .. controls (5.5199,4.9606) and (5.5290,5.0029) .. (5.5366,5.0470) 
                .. controls (5.5445,5.0924) and (5.5537,5.1283) .. (5.5579,5.1297) 
                .. controls (5.5620,5.1310) and (5.5700,5.1276) .. (5.5756,5.1219) 
                .. controls (5.5812,5.1163) and (5.5879,5.1140) .. (5.5905,5.1168) 
                .. controls (5.5930,5.1195) and (5.6027,5.1667) .. (5.6119,5.2214) 
                .. controls (5.6332,5.3474) and (5.6318,5.3429) .. (5.6501,5.3429) 
                .. controls (5.6719,5.3429) and (5.6733,5.3476) .. (5.6966,5.4970) 
                .. controls (5.7041,5.5457) and (5.7125,5.5531) .. (5.7298,5.5267) 
                -- (6,5.5531) -- (0,0) -- (0,7.2111) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You scaling is a little bit excessive. This is what I get if I scale your code. Is this what you want?:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \definecolor{vua}{RGB}{106,153,218}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,scale=0.05,yscale=0.5]
        \shadedraw[vua,top color=vua!30!white, bottom color=white,ultra thick] (0.4235,7.2111) .. controls (0.4185,7.1960) and (0.4609,7.2095) .. (0.4817,7.2296) .. controls (0.5018,7.2491) and (0.5225,7.2535) .. (0.5329,7.2404) .. controls (0.5363,7.2361) and (0.5454,7.2084) .. (0.5531,7.1788) .. controls (0.5721,7.1057) and (0.5742,7.1033) .. (0.5959,7.1293) .. controls (0.6153,7.1526) and (0.6228,7.1515) .. (0.6374,7.1233) .. controls (0.6426,7.1132) and (0.6508,7.1050) .. (0.6555,7.1050) .. controls (0.6603,7.1050) and (0.6781,7.1206) .. (0.6952,7.1397) .. controls (0.7122,7.1588) and (0.7276,7.1721) .. (0.7293,7.1693) .. controls (0.7310,7.1664) and (0.7385,7.1277) .. (0.7459,7.0832) .. controls (0.7641,6.9739) and (0.7709,6.9684) .. (0.7954,7.0434) .. controls (0.8028,7.0660) and (0.8171,7.0975) .. (0.8272,7.1134) .. controls (0.8423,7.1373) and (0.8487,7.1423) .. (0.8642,7.1423) .. controls (0.8850,7.1423) and (0.8931,7.1522) .. (0.9119,7.2006) .. controls (0.9323,7.2533) and (0.9506,7.2453) .. (0.9764,7.1723) .. controls (0.9850,7.1477) and (0.9949,7.1267) .. (0.9984,7.1256) .. controls (1.0018,7.1245) and (1.0123,7.1362) .. (1.0216,7.1517) .. controls (1.0309,7.1671) and (1.0409,7.1797) .. (1.0439,7.1797) .. controls (1.0513,7.1797) and (1.0682,7.1604) .. (1.0912,7.1256) .. controls (1.1062,7.1028) and (1.1167,7.0944) .. (1.1394,7.0867) .. controls (1.1742,7.0750) and (1.1917,7.0601) .. (1.2079,7.0282) .. controls (1.2157,7.0130) and (1.2277,7.0012) .. (1.2411,6.9956) .. controls (1.2555,6.9896) and (1.2686,6.9760) .. (1.2826,6.9526) .. controls (1.2963,6.9298) and (1.3091,6.9163) .. (1.3213,6.9121) .. controls (1.3431,6.9045) and (1.3507,6.9094) .. (1.3700,6.9439) .. controls (1.3837,6.9683) and (1.3993,6.9744) .. (1.4111,6.9602) .. controls (1.4160,6.9543) and (1.4498,6.8007) .. (1.4498,6.7843) .. controls (1.4498,6.7741) and (1.4676,6.7838) .. (1.4737,6.7972) .. controls (1.4778,6.8061) and (1.4843,6.8122) .. (1.4882,6.8109) .. controls (1.4922,6.8096) and (1.5028,6.7705) .. (1.5118,6.7241) .. controls (1.5257,6.6530) and (1.5313,6.6359) .. (1.5474,6.6155) .. controls (1.5592,6.6006) and (1.5741,6.5672) .. (1.5861,6.5290) .. controls (1.6045,6.4700) and (1.6312,6.4263) .. (1.6488,6.4263) .. controls (1.6522,6.4263) and (1.6633,6.4427) .. (1.6735,6.4628) .. controls (1.6901,6.4957) and (1.6949,6.5003) .. (1.7218,6.5092) .. controls (1.7450,6.5169) and (1.7533,6.5174) .. (1.7587,6.5116) .. controls (1.7625,6.5075) and (1.7707,6.4789) .. (1.7768,6.4481) .. controls (1.7914,6.3750) and (1.7940,6.3702) .. (1.8204,6.3702) .. controls (1.8385,6.3702) and (1.8444,6.3664) .. (1.8582,6.3455) .. controls (1.8764,6.3181) and (1.9089,6.3063) .. (1.9301,6.3196) .. controls (1.9492,6.3315) and (1.9534,6.3280) .. (1.9637,6.2909) .. controls (1.9841,6.2177) and (1.9859,6.2143) .. (2.0110,6.1985) .. controls (2.0402,6.1801) and (2.0635,6.1452) .. (2.0849,6.0881) .. controls (2.0934,6.0652) and (2.1039,6.0465) .. (2.1081,6.0465) .. controls (2.1124,6.0465) and (2.1199,6.0563) .. (2.1249,6.0683) .. controls (2.1299,6.0802) and (2.1369,6.0900) .. (2.1405,6.0900) .. controls (2.1474,6.0900) and (2.1480,6.0880) .. (2.1643,6.0092) .. controls (2.1788,5.9388) and (2.1902,5.9357) .. (2.2058,5.9980) .. controls (2.2195,6.0526) and (2.2375,6.0963) .. (2.2462,6.0963) .. controls (2.2565,6.0963) and (2.2634,6.0780) .. (2.2776,6.0122) .. controls (2.2850,5.9780) and (2.2937,5.9473) .. (2.2969,5.9441) .. controls (2.3057,5.9352) and (2.3363,5.9677) .. (2.3590,6.0104) .. controls (2.3774,6.0449) and (2.3803,6.0475) .. (2.3963,6.0443) .. controls (2.4066,6.0422) and (2.4161,6.0439) .. (2.4195,6.0483) .. controls (2.4309,6.0633) and (2.4647,6.2138) .. (2.4771,6.3049) .. controls (2.4947,6.4335) and (2.4923,6.4263) .. (2.5167,6.4263) .. controls (2.5371,6.4263) and (2.5830,6.4518) .. (2.6031,6.4744) .. controls (2.6085,6.4805) and (2.6189,6.5057) .. (2.6262,6.5306) .. controls (2.6335,6.5554) and (2.6419,6.5757) .. (2.6448,6.5757) .. controls (2.6477,6.5757) and (2.6562,6.5596) .. (2.6638,6.5399) .. controls (2.6714,6.5202) and (2.6854,6.4859) .. (2.6949,6.4636) .. controls (2.7132,6.4211) and (2.7342,6.3482) .. (2.7642,6.2239) .. controls (2.7870,6.1292) and (2.7895,6.1238) .. (2.8125,6.1192) .. controls (2.8301,6.1157) and (2.8324,6.1117) .. (2.8482,6.0591) .. controls (2.8664,5.9986) and (2.8753,5.9908) .. (2.8912,6.0216) .. controls (2.8965,6.0318) and (2.9034,6.0402) .. (2.9065,6.0402) .. controls (2.9127,6.0402) and (2.9129,6.0395) .. (2.9313,5.9722) .. controls (2.9438,5.9264) and (2.9677,5.8908) .. (2.9859,5.8908) .. controls (2.9905,5.8908) and (2.9974,5.8985) .. (3.0013,5.9079) .. controls (3.0452,6.0142) and (3.0542,6.0157) .. (3.0841,5.9219) .. controls (3.1023,5.8650) and (3.1316,5.8020) .. (3.1528,5.7742) .. controls (3.1664,5.7564) and (3.1772,5.7309) .. (3.1860,5.6956) .. controls (3.2033,5.6266) and (3.2098,5.6106) .. (3.2203,5.6106) .. controls (3.2291,5.6106) and (3.2649,5.6477) .. (3.2778,5.6701) .. controls (3.2845,5.6816) and (3.2848,5.6816) .. (3.2911,5.6696) .. controls (3.2947,5.6628) and (3.3036,5.6281) .. (3.3108,5.5924) .. controls (3.3181,5.5567) and (3.3252,5.5263) .. (3.3267,5.5248) .. controls (3.3338,5.5177) and (3.3467,5.5367) .. (3.3718,5.5913) .. controls (3.4131,5.6813) and (3.4122,5.6798) .. (3.4261,5.6778) .. controls (3.4362,5.6764) and (3.4428,5.6637) .. (3.4580,5.6168) .. controls (3.4750,5.5644) and (3.4794,5.5567) .. (3.4969,5.5489) .. controls (3.5132,5.5416) and (3.5187,5.5333) .. (3.5292,5.5009) .. controls (3.5362,5.4793) and (3.5420,5.4567) .. (3.5421,5.4505) .. controls (3.5423,5.4365) and (3.5526,5.4236) .. (3.5751,5.4092) .. controls (3.5981,5.3945) and (3.6061,5.3984) .. (3.6164,5.4295) .. controls (3.6211,5.4437) and (3.6279,5.4543) .. (3.6316,5.4530) .. controls (3.6353,5.4518) and (3.6442,5.4030) .. (3.6515,5.3443) .. controls (3.6588,5.2857) and (3.6664,5.2334) .. (3.6685,5.2281) .. controls (3.6756,5.2095) and (3.6841,5.2185) .. (3.6975,5.2587) .. controls (3.7049,5.2810) and (3.7133,5.3006) .. (3.7162,5.3024) .. controls (3.7191,5.3042) and (3.7266,5.2990) .. (3.7330,5.2910) .. controls (3.7468,5.2734) and (3.7669,5.2619) .. (3.7838,5.2619) .. controls (3.7913,5.2619) and (3.8116,5.2792) .. (3.8352,5.3058) .. controls (3.8942,5.3721) and (3.8949,5.3715) .. (3.9191,5.2277) .. controls (3.9300,5.1626) and (3.9393,5.1081) .. (3.9397,5.1066) .. controls (3.9401,5.1052) and (3.9485,5.1117) .. (3.9584,5.1212) .. controls (3.9683,5.1307) and (3.9778,5.1361) .. (3.9795,5.1332) .. controls (3.9812,5.1304) and (3.9875,5.1098) .. (3.9934,5.0876) .. controls (3.9994,5.0653) and (4.0150,5.0257) .. (4.0281,4.9995) .. controls (4.0487,4.9583) and (4.0541,4.9378) .. (4.0684,4.8470) .. controls (4.0774,4.7892) and (4.0859,4.7385) .. (4.0871,4.7342) .. controls (4.0918,4.7184) and (4.1074,4.7271) .. (4.1169,4.7508) .. controls (4.1222,4.7642) and (4.1294,4.7769) .. (4.1329,4.7790) .. controls (4.1363,4.7812) and (4.1537,4.7536) .. (4.1718,4.7173) .. controls (4.1898,4.6812) and (4.2077,4.6517) .. (4.2116,4.6517) .. controls (4.2160,4.6517) and (4.2243,4.6861) .. (4.2330,4.7404) .. controls (4.2408,4.7892) and (4.2498,4.8320) .. (4.2530,4.8354) .. controls (4.2568,4.8395) and (4.2628,4.8368) .. (4.2703,4.8276) .. controls (4.2861,4.8083) and (4.2936,4.8100) .. (4.3042,4.8354) .. controls (4.3123,4.8546) and (4.3264,4.8655) .. (4.3264,4.8524) .. controls (4.3264,4.8417) and (4.3572,4.6998) .. (4.3602,4.6968) .. controls (4.3619,4.6950) and (4.3704,4.6982) .. (4.3789,4.7038) .. controls (4.3875,4.7094) and (4.3959,4.7140) .. (4.3977,4.7140) .. controls (4.3995,4.7140) and (4.4079,4.7002) .. (4.4165,4.6833) .. controls (4.4340,4.6487) and (4.4427,4.6410) .. (4.4527,4.6510) .. controls (4.4762,4.6745) and (4.4995,4.6339) .. (4.5342,4.5085) .. controls (4.5590,4.4189) and (4.6162,4.2788) .. (4.6302,4.2735) .. controls (4.6489,4.2663) and (4.6789,4.3095) .. (4.6911,4.3614) .. controls (4.6973,4.3877) and (4.7052,4.4082) .. (4.7087,4.4070) .. controls (4.7122,4.4058) and (4.7209,4.3813) .. (4.7279,4.3524) .. controls (4.7355,4.3212) and (4.7498,4.2848) .. (4.7632,4.2626) .. controls (4.7756,4.2420) and (4.7917,4.2133) .. (4.7990,4.1987) .. controls (4.8080,4.1809) and (4.8198,4.1687) .. (4.8353,4.1614) .. controls (4.8552,4.1519) and (4.8606,4.1443) .. (4.8759,4.1041) .. controls (4.8971,4.0484) and (4.9298,4.0058) .. (4.9534,4.0030) .. controls (4.9661,4.0015) and (4.9748,3.9930) .. (4.9897,3.9676) .. controls (5.0005,3.9491) and (5.0161,3.9303) .. (5.0243,3.9258) .. controls (5.0551,3.9087) and (5.0585,3.9126) .. (5.0762,3.9839) .. controls (5.0854,4.0207) and (5.1022,4.0719) .. (5.1137,4.0976) .. controls (5.1415,4.1600) and (5.1449,4.1752) .. (5.1605,4.3093) .. controls (5.1678,4.3726) and (5.1807,4.4679) .. (5.1891,4.5210) .. controls (5.2379,4.8307) and (5.2469,4.8744) .. (5.2722,4.9245) .. controls (5.2821,4.9440) and (5.2948,4.9837) .. (5.3006,5.0129) .. controls (5.3181,5.1018) and (5.3218,5.1060) .. (5.3382,5.0565) .. controls (5.3505,5.0194) and (5.3556,5.0153) .. (5.3738,5.0281) .. controls (5.3815,5.0334) and (5.3907,5.0378) .. (5.3944,5.0378) .. controls (5.3981,5.0378) and (5.4147,5.0152) .. (5.4314,4.9877) .. controls (5.4480,4.9602) and (5.4641,4.9361) .. (5.4670,4.9343) .. controls (5.4781,4.9275) and (5.5104,4.9397) .. (5.5165,4.9530) .. controls (5.5199,4.9606) and (5.5290,5.0029) .. (5.5366,5.0470) .. controls (5.5445,5.0924) and (5.5537,5.1283) .. (5.5579,5.1297) .. controls (5.5620,5.1310) and (5.5700,5.1276) .. (5.5756,5.1219) .. controls (5.5812,5.1163) and (5.5879,5.1140) .. (5.5905,5.1168) .. controls (5.5930,5.1195) and (5.6027,5.1667) .. (5.6119,5.2214) .. controls (5.6332,5.3474) and (5.6318,5.3429) .. (5.6501,5.3429) .. controls (5.6719,5.3429) and (5.6733,5.3476) .. (5.6966,5.4970) .. controls (5.7041,5.5457) and (5.7125,5.5531) .. (5.7298,5.5267) -- (current page.south east) -- (current page.south west) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Roland, Ideally I don't want to show any smooth borders. The hypothetical stock price process should "move in and move out" of the frame.