# "Thank You" slide in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

The last slide on presentation is usually, "Thank You" or "Thanks for a Patient Hearing" or something like that. Are there any showcases/ examples of nice last Beamer slides to be included in presentations?

Comment: A friend of mine put a beautiful equation on the Thank you slide, which was completely unrelated to the subject :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is one I use in most of my presentations  with applicable change in image, text, text size, text font and text color.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]

  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        \pgfimage[width=\textwidth]{figures/thankyouimage}          
      \end{center}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.75\textwidth}
      \begin{center}

        \font\endfont = cmss10 at 25.40mm
        \color{Brown}
        \endfont 
        \baselineskip 20.0mm

        Thank you

      \end{center}    

    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use ready made images as a full slide, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3915/14103)  will
be useful.

Comment: Dear Masroor, may I ask you how to put some commands written in a software's envirounment in Latex beamer?

Comment: @B.S. [list­ings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) can be used like it can be used in other documents. Also see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197988/lstlistings-does-not-work-in-a-slide).