# lstlistings does not work in a slide

Tags: beamer, listings

I am writing a slide. I want to use `lstlisting`

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern} 
    \usepackage{listings}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{HeartBleed}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    Hellow world  
   \end{lstlisting}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

I get an error around around `\begin{lstlisting}` and it says: `job aborted, no legal \end found`. How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the usage of `listings` you have to use the `fragile` option for the `frame`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \begin{lstlisting}
            Hello world  
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Further information can be at found http://pbelmans.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/why-latex-beamer-needs-fragile-when-using-verbatim/

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, and this is very useful for my presentation as I have to do that on several slides.