# Beamer theme with different frame types

Tags: beamer, themes

I've been following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch) post to create my own theme.  However, I would like to create a Beamer theme which supports different look and feel for different frame types.  Here are some examples:

A frame which has a full-page background image, a title, and a subtitle.  Here is some made up code which does not compile:

```
\begin{frame}{picture}
  \framepic{images/bg.jpg}
  \frametitle{Nothing was the same.}
  Always felt like my vision been bigger than the bigger picture.
\end{frame}
```

Which may look like this:
[image]

Or a frame with a title and a list.  Here is some more made up code:

```
\begin{frame}{list}
  \frametitle{Frank Ocean}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \emph{Tuesday}
    \item Thinking About You
    \item Sweet Life
    \item Not Just Money
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Which may look like this:
[image]

I suppose I can just create my own separate set of commands using \newcommand and \newenvironment, however, I was hoping to use Beamer idiomatic commands to do this.

Is this at all possible?  What would be a clean approach?

Comment: For your first requirement, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3927/32374

Comment: I don't really understand the second. You put the enumeration inside the frame. I don't see how you could specify that as a frame type.

Comment: Hi, I added some code and visalization.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start with darthbith's suggestion.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{picture}
  %\framepic{images/bg.jpg}
  \frametitle{Nothing was the same.}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[at=(current page.center)] {
                \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{bg}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
  Always felt like my vision been bigger than the bigger picture.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{list}
  \frametitle{Frank Ocean}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \emph{Tuesday}
    \item Thinking About You
    \item Sweet Life
    \item Not Just Money
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible suggestion, as you'd like to define several frames types...

I used this definition to print a separation frame with some text in the middle.

```
\newcommand{\sepframe}[1]{
  \begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[font=\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{grayd},text width=10cm,text badly centered] at (current page.center) {\uppercase\expandafter{#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
}
```

In the document content, I would call sepframe like this:

```
\begin{document}
% Some frames...

\sepframe{Next topic}

% Some frames...
\end{document}
```

This kind of approach would work great for your picture stuff, but not exactly for the list... In the end isn't it just a frame with an `itemize` inside?