# Image on full slide

Tags: beamer

I am trying to achieve a result similar to the one described here: [Image on full slide in beamer package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/image-on-full-slide-in-beamer-package)

but with a variant. Specifically I would like to put the figure in the whole slide but  below the navigation bar. Any idea of how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how much space occupies the navigation bar? If your answer is yes, you can use something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \parbox[c][\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth}{%
        \vspace*{.1\paperheight}%
        \includegraphics[height=.9\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The height of the headline is accessible via `\headheight`