# Image on full slide considering a frametitle

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I am using the following example from tex stack to crate a PDF-page with a picture centered over a page: [Image on full slide in beamer package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/image-on-full-slide-in-beamer-package)

The code I use from the example is this one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{test of full size graphic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
    Notice the fancy presentation theme.
\end{frame}

{ % all template changes are local to this group.
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{frame}<article:0>[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[at=(current page.center)] {
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,
                                 width=\paperwidth,
                                 height=\paperheight]{yourimage}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    symbols should be back now
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, I want to add a frametitle to the page like this:

```
\begin{frame}{Some random data that I use and want to describe (yearly)}
```

When I do that the picture that I insert centres vertically over the page, not considering that there now is a frametitle to consider. The image thus overlays part of the frametitle. Can I use some code to make the image vertically center over the page considering the space required for the frametitle? That is, centring it over the white space on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually positioning the image, you could let beamer do its job:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{test of full size graphic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
    Notice the fancy presentation theme.
\end{frame}

{ % all template changes are local to this group.
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{frame}<article:0>[plain]
    \frametitle{Some random data that I use and want to describe (yearly)}
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{\paperwidth}
    \includegraphics[
                    keepaspectratio,
                                     width=\paperwidth,
                                     height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
     \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    symbols should be back now
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works fine. How do I center the image vertically and horizontally?